# How to check file size and type of captured video using Android Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video-capture

I'm using `Intent` for capturing video. Now i want to get the file name, file size and file type of the recorded video.

```
private String videoPath = "";

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {

          Uri vid = data.getData();
          videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(vid);
        }


    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

I am getting  the file name using the above method `getRealPathFromURI()`. Now how to retrieve the file size and type? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a comment on the answer below, you said you had found a solution. Do you mind posting a link to it/answer describing what you did? I came here looking for how to get the file size from a share Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image in Bitmap Then can get the values

Check this

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
              Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                System.out.println("sizeeee---"+ image.getByteCount());

          Uri vid = data.getData();
          videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(vid);
        }


    }
```

Comment: It's giving me crash. But i made it work using another way. Do you know how to get the file type?

Comment: System.out.println("type------"+data.getExtras().get("data"));

Comment: see this ,it will return a  bitmap

Comment: It's still giving crash

Comment: It's fine. I tried another way and got the desired output